# Do two subjects need to be connected by a conjunction

Tags: grammar

> Temporary-employment agencies benefit not only from the increasing demand for clerical workers but also from the higher profits made when highly paid professionals are placed, requests for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover.

I am confused about the lack of conjunction after the comma. The way I see it, there are two main subjects, *temporary-employment agencies* and *requests*, but there is no conjunction to connect them.

Comment: The text ***requests for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover*** is not a "sentence". It's not even a valid sequence of words that could form ***part*** of a sentence. The text ***Temporary-employment agencies benefit not only from the increasing demand for clerical workers but also from the higher profits made when highly paid professionals are placed*** is a perfectly valid sentence that includes the conjunction ***but***. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I've tried editing it into shape. Have a look if I've missed something. And make sure to never use parentheses the way you did. That is highly unusual at best, and incomprehensible at worst. Thank you.

Comment: *Requests for whom* seems to simply be modifying the previous noun rather than serving as a final list item. It could be parsed in the same way as *when highly paid professionals (requests for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover), are placed.* Either that or it's modifying both the highly paid professionals and the clerical workers—it's somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Note that, to me, the editing of the question doesn't seem to have clarified your question. (Although, granted, it wasn't clear before.) If you are unhappy with what's been done, please roll it back to its original version. If you do, please include the *original* version of the sentence in addition to your attempt at parsing it.

Comment: Your sentence looks fine to me. The expression "requests for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover" is a supplementary relative clause in which the relative phrase "requests for whom" is subject and "whom" anaphoric to "highly paid professionals".

Comment: It's a side comment meaning *whose popularity has increased*.

Answer (score 1):

Something has gone wrong with the sentence you quote, for sure, but adding a conjunction before "requests" doesn't really help. I'd suggest replacing that last observation, beginning with "requests", with

> (Such requests for highly paid professionals have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeovers.)

I can parse the original example in this way: "requests for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover" is an extraposed relative clause which modifies "highly paid professionals".  Before extraposition, this has the form

> ... when highly paid professionals requests for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover are placed.

which, IMO, is grammatical, though very awkward, because of the overly complex subject.  Sometimes, in such constructions, the awkwardness can be avoided by moving ("extraposing") the relative clause to the end of the clause.  Doing this leads us to your example sentence.  But something goes wrong. I don't know what constraint has been violated, but the result is, IMO, ungrammatical in English.

I don't doubt that you've quoted the example correctly, and as I've just said, I don't know why it wouldn't be grammatical.  But nonetheless, IMO as a native speaker of English, that sentence is no good.  It just isn't grammatical.

Comment: Temporary-employment agencies benefit not only from the increasing demand for clerical workers but also the higher profits made when from the higher profits made in placing highly paid professionals, requests whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeovers. im so sorry that is the correct sentence

Comment: @loleon, I added some additional explanation to my original answer.

Comment: "Requests [for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover]" is surely an NP, with the noun "requests" as head and the bracketed relative clause modifying the head. The whole NP is then just a supplement whose 'anchor' is "higher paid professionals".

Comment: @BillJ, No, it isn't.  "requests for whom" is the NP subject of "have" in the relative clause.  It's a relative expression formed by the "pied-piping" convention, so named by Robin Lakoff.

Comment: Of course!  "... "the higher profits made when **highly paid professionals** are placed, [requests for **whom** have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover]. Thanks for that.

Comment: Hard disagree that anything has "gone wrong" in this sentence. It's not the most well-constructed sentence ever, but it makes perfect sense to me as a native speaker. I see no grammatical errors or anything that's invalid English. Just a bit of complicated structure.

Answer (score 0):

> Temporary-employment agencies benefit not only from the increasing demand for clerical workers but also from the higher profits made when highly paid professionals are placed, requests for whom have increased in the recent wave of corporate takeover.

If we simplify, we have:

**They** benefit from **this** and from **profits from some people** for whom requests have increased.

There are not “two subjects”: there two prepositional adverbial clauses

> (i)    from the increasing demand for clerical workers

and

> (ii)   from the higher profits made when highly paid professionals are placed

The prepositional adverbial clauses are joined by the conjunction “but”